# control Turtlebot Waffle Pi (movement, set/get velocity) via openCR Microcontroller

Tags: ros, turtlebot3, opencr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

In our project, we need to control the Turtlebot3 Waffle Pi with following commands:

```
- move to a position
- stop moving
- set & get velocity
- set & get angular velocity
```

What we plan to do is: We have a C++ project in Windows and it sends a message to the OpenCR MCU via UART. The OpenCR MCU will analyse the message and issue a corresponding command (move, stop, set/get velocity etc.) to the Waffle Pi.

Is it possible to do this? Is there any tutorial or example project which shows how to do this?

Thanks

Bien

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318932/control-turtlebot-waffle-pi-(movement,-set/get-velocity)-via-opencr-microcontroller/) by [bienle](https://answers.ros.org/users/40536/bienle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Bien.

What you want seems to be possible enough.
However, unfortunately, there are no official tutorials or examples related to this.
So.. you have to modify the core of TB3 yourself and use it.

If you want to keep the basic functions of the core as full as possible, you can use Serial2 to receive the data.

Below are links to the basic examples of TB3 core and OpenCR. Please refer to these.

- [OpenCR TB3 core examples](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/tree/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/turtlebot3/examples)
- [OpenCR examples](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/tree/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/OpenCR/examples)

---

Originally posted by [Kei](https://answers.ros.org/users/36003/kei/) with karma: 28 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0